# Postgresql: Query list of connections LISTENing to a channel

Tags: postgresql

How to query a list of connected clients that are listening on a LISTEN/NOTIFY channel?

Most documentation regarding client activity points to pg_stat_activity, however, this does not show which connections are listening for notifications.